# The scripts tags in HTML page fail with HTTP status code 401

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http-status-code-401, hapi.js

I created an application with node.js and hapi.js.
In the `index.HTML` page I have the following script tags:

```
<script src="./rootApp1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./Shell.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when I run the page they fail with status 401.

In the debugger the type of this scripts is `json/application` but in fact the physical script type is `type="text/javascript"`

Could this be the problem?

The router in the server side:

```
server.route({//open the index
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{param*}',
        handler:{
            directory: {
                path: './client/app/',

                index:true
            }
        },
        config: { auth: false }
    }
);
```

The external scripts load without problems.

How can I resolve the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the path could be wrong for both resources. Go to the path your scripts are stored and copy paste the folder address into the question.

Comment: What the meaning?change the path in the script or show it here? (It doesnt work without the ./ also)

Comment: 401 means authorization error, i.e. access to the resource requires authorization, normally a username/password combination.

Comment: In last, it work. suddenly the error apear.

Comment: maybe it because upgrade hapi version to 8.1.0?